# Keep the alignment of my block

Tags: html, css

I have a table with cell, in my cell i have a `<div>` with `<p>`

***html:***

```
<td data-ng-repeat="price in goHead.prices track by $index">
  <div>
      <p data-ng-if="price.isMinPrice"><img src="images/lemoinscher.png"/></p>
      <p data-ng-if="!price.isMinPrice"></p>
      <p style="font-size:16px;text-align:center;">{{price.price}}</p>

      <p data-ng-if="price.isLastPlace" class="lasptlace"  data-ng-bind-html="'matrice.lastplace' | translate"></p>
      <p data-ng-if="!price.isLastPlace" class="lasptlace"  ></p>
  </div>
</td>
```

***css:***

```
.matrices div p {
    display: table-row-group;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}

.matrices div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My pb is when i hide a `<p>` block my block are no longer properly aligned, what is wrong ..?

[image: Represent 2 cell of my table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the default vertical alignment of your table cells compensating for the item's display being changed, when set to `display:none` an element no longer has any dimensions, which is reflected on the layout. As the default vertical alignment for a table cell is `middle` if you hide the preceding content by changing its display value, the subsequent content is 'shifted up'. You can maintain the same positioning by:

1. Setting `visibility:hidden` instead.
2. Setting `opacity:0;` instead
3. Changing/reversing the `vertical-align` value for the parent cell (e.g. to 'bottom', 'baseline')
4. Absolutely positioning the content within the cell